# how to get option menu on android api level 12 emulator?

Tags: android, menu, emulation, optionmenu

I am new to work with android tablet api level 12. I have created 7 inches avd with 1024*600 screen resolution. I have implemented sample application for get the option menus on my screen and back button. I am unable to see option button and back button on my emulator.

I have implemented for option menu code as follows:

```
  @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

     return true;
 }


 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.icon:     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
    case R.id.text:     Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
    case R.id.icontext: Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the icon and text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you check the actionbar on the top right?

Comment: in your case statements, you are using `R.id.icon`. You should be using the id that you have given for these menu items in the menu xml file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use keyboard shortcuts to simulate the hardware buttons. There's a table of the shortcuts [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#KeyMapping). The Back button is simulated by pressing escape, and the menu button is simulated by the Page-Up or F2 keys.

Comment: The short key F2 or Page-Up are not working in android api levele 13.How can i get option menu in android api level 13.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary options menus will appear regardless of Android version. If you have:

android:targetSdkVersion="11"

then the options menu will appear in the action bar on Android 3.0+ devices. All items in the options menu will be available when clicking the "overflow" button in the upper-right corner. Your options menu will appear normally on Android 1.x and 2.x devices, even if you have android:targetSdkVersion="11" in your  manifest element.

If you overrode the MENU button to have other behavior, you will need to create some other trigger for that behavior for API Level 11 and higher. Overriding the MENU button was never a good idea to begin with, and as you can see, it is even less of a good idea now. I know of no way to get a MENU button on an Android 3.0 device if you have 
android:targetSdkVersion="11".

Answer (score 1):

As you said "I am unable to see option button and back button on my emulator"
SO its does not make a sense that you have posted your code because you can't changes the hardware as programmatically.

and

- for menu u can press **F2**
- for back u can press **Esc**

Answer (score 1):

Short update: a current list of commands is found at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#tasks.

For the menu, you are supposed to use <kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd> (on a Mac: <kbd>Command-M</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

For windows 10 you have to open your emulator, then press Ctrl + M 
and the menu will show.